# Property 'value' is missing in type '{ children: any; }' but required in type 'ProviderProps<{}>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

Error
Property 'value' is missing in type '{ children: any; }' but required in type 'ProviderProps<{}>'.ts(2741)
index.d.ts(338, 9): 'value' is declared here.

I am attempting to convert a JS file into a typescript project, but having issues with types. I do not want to disable the strict mode on typescript to circumvent the issue, as I feel like this does not solve the issue.

Building a globalcontet

Here is GlobalContextProvider.JS

```
import React from 'react';

export const GlobalStateContext = React.createContext()
export const GlobalDispatchContext = React.createContext()


const initialState = {
    partner: 'none'
}

function reducer(state, action) {
switch (action.type){
    case 'TOGGLE_PARTNER': {
        return{
            ...state,
            partner: state.partner === 'none' ? 'active' : 'none'
        }
    }
    default:
        throw new Error('Bad Action Type')
}
}

const GlobalContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState)  
    return <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={state}><GlobalDispatchContext.Provider>{children}</GlobalDispatchContext.Provider></GlobalStateContext.Provider>
}

export default GlobalContextProvider
```

Here is my attempt that has the error:
GlobalContextProvider.TSX

```
import React from "react"

export const GlobalStateContext = React.createContext({})
export const GlobalDispatchContext = React.createContext({})

const initialState = {
    partner: "none",
}

function reducer(state: any, action: any) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "TOGGLE_PARTNER": {
            return {
                ...state,
                partner: state.partner === "none" ? "active" : "none",
            }
        }
        default:
            throw new Error("Bad Action Type")
    }
}

const GlobalContextProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState)
    return (
        <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={state}>
            <GlobalDispatchContext.Provider>
                {children}
            </GlobalDispatchContext.Provider>
        </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default GlobalContextProvider
```

src/context/GlobalContextProvider.tsx:3:41 - error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

27             <GlobalDispatchContext.Provider>

Comment: Doesn't `GlobalDispatchContext.Provider` need a value?

Comment: `GlobalDispatchContext.Provider` isn't actually doing anything, you should remove it (you can always add it back in if you have a need for it). Also, use `React.PropsWithChildren` instead of `any` for props.